# Does it make sense to authenticate a method that exposes non-sensitive data

Tags: architecture, security, web-services

We're developing an Angular application that consumes a web method exposing some information that is not sensitive, just bus seat promotions; the user enters where he wants to go and when and he will be presented with the available offers (if any). The site does not require any kind of authentication for this information is publicly available and it is just trying to offer an easy way to gather this information for the public.

There's been an argument about whether it is convenient to implement OAUTH on the service itself, creating a service account for the angular application so we know that no one else is trying to access this information. The way I see it, I don't think it is necessary, this is publicly available info and if they want to access it they can parse the information on the site or even figure out the credentials that the Angular app is using. Is there any benefit that I'm missing here?

Comment: Someone can automated request to your web method and your server would be down. Is it kind of secure what you consider ?

Comment: Does not this also apply to the site itself? Some could request my site a zillion times and get the same result.

Comment: Could someone take profit of such public resources so that could make you lose gains? I ask this because I know a case where a casual developer defeated an official app creating a better one based on the public API of the former.

Comment: Don't really think so, this site is not meant to make any kind of profit, it does not even allow buying the seats. The whole point of this app is to take away some load from the main app in which you can buy the tickets so it is not disturbed by people looking for promotions but not actually buying anything.

Comment: It's not about buying, it's about unfair competition.

Comment: I see that, but if the site's purpose is just to reduce the load on the main site that does allow actually buying the tickets and no profit is expected I don't see the harm on someone building a better site.

Comment: Someone building a better site at expenses of yours is a better site withdrawing potential customers (hence gains) at your expenses too. In other words, you might end up paying someone else bills and losing gains at the same time. Don't look at this from the technical standpoint, look at it from the business strategical standpoint. Think if someone can take advantage of you.

Comment: Again, this site has no customers, it's just a lookup page so the actual vending site is not overloaded when people is looking for promotions but not actually buying anything. It has no adds and people interested in buying will be redirected to the company's vending site. The way I see it if someone happens to create a site that is more successful than this one it's not harming the company (they will be redirected to the company's site to buy the tickets).

Comment: Also from a technical standpoint reverse engineering the angular site to see the service account secret that it is using to authenticate the calls is not really hard, is it?

Comment: Where a person wants to go and when *is* sensitive data that the user may not want to share with third parties. Consider for a moment the things a malicious actor could do with that information.

Comment: I agree, but that data is protected, endpoints encrypt their data and searches logs are not retrievable, no service exposes it. By not authenticating what you allow is anyone to invoke the service to perform a search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Authentication does more than protect data. It protects a resource.

You say the data is publicly available but is the service meant to be publicly available? Being publicly available costs time and money. For example, now you need a plan for handling DDoS attacks.

Now sure, implementing OATH costs time and money as well. That's why asking "is it convenient?" is a very wise question. Identify the risks and estimate the potential for damage. Then estimate the cost of mitigating those risks.

This is called [cost benefit analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost%E2%80%93benefit_analysis). It can help you make this decision. However it has a downside. Some companies obsess on mitigating risk. Trying to apply this can give you tunnel vision. You start to think cost is the only consideration.

Time is another huge one. Many potential problems are best dealt with once they're actual problems. Why? Because what we predict and what happens are rarely the same.

Public relations shouldn't be ignored either. Maybe you think this data isn't sensitive in this context but if you let anyone have it then it can end up it very different contexts and be analyzed in ways you never intended. You'll only learn how once it hits the news.

But maybe making this data publicly available **on your site** is for the public good. Maybe it will help promote your company. If that makes this all worth it to your company then go ahead.

Comment: In this case data is publicly available by definition and hugely unlikely to change, the site is just for looking at promotion, they can't even buy any seats on the bus. Also the site does not have any kind of authentication either. Sure DDos is a concern but the same applies to the site. If it was my call, maybe I would invoke these services on the server side and then there would be just one point of entry for this type of attacks but that part of the architecture is closed.

Comment: @Zalomon then consider how hard it would be to identify traffic hitting your service that isn't coming from your application. As long as you don't lose the ability to separate them later if needed it's likely ok not to care now.

Comment: Imagine you have to scale the service because someone is consuming your service. Would you be "happy" paying the bills?

Comment: Of course not, but how's that different from people accessing the site massively?? I don't think authenticating the call to the webservice is the solution for this.

Comment: People accessing the site massively see your adds massively (or whatever else you're promoting). People consuming the service only get your data. If your OK with that fine. If so I'd love to know how your business plan works.

Comment: It's no business plan at all. It's a project of the bus operator to mitigate the load in their ticket selling site on promotion days, with people looking for offers but buying nothing. So they want users looking in this new site and if they decide to buy a ticket redirect them to the old site with their selection preloaded.

Comment: @Zalomon hmm so you're really just promoting the data. How refreshing.

Comment: It is a scenario in which the operator wants a separate search page so the vending page is not overloaded when they release a new promotion, because a lot of people enters the page when there's a new promotion just out of curiosity without actually buying. It's not like I want to promote new data out of the goodnes of my heart.

Comment: But you are doing that if you don't constrain the access to such data. Bear in mind that on the internet, there are not only humans crawling around looking for p...n. There're bots too, scraping the web, mining data